# Dynamic SQL query for SharePoint lists for look ups values

Tags: data, bdc, connection

I'm trying to link an external sql large table (10000 Rows) into SharePoint 2010 to be used as a look up ( eg to select an existing customer) in the metadata of documents.

I have a BDC External Content Type created but it can't return all the rows in the table.

Is there a way of doing this **simply** as I am not looking to code?

Can it be done using a dynamic query into SQL to pull back the data without using BDC?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

Only BCS/BDC, External Content Types are the way Out of the Box available (if you don't want to code).. AFAIK

However if you choose to code you can use .Net Framework to query database and show data in Web Parts etc.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Arsalan. I was afraid that would be the answer. I may have resolved the issue in any event but thank you for the input.